# How to use short cut keys to insert get set code of data member in visual studio?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

How to use short cut keys to insert get set code of data member in visual studio?

I think it is some tab.

Answer (score 3):

Try to type "prop" and press twice <kbd>TAB</kbd> and you'll see someting cool. (at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

To get the full property for the getter and setter method type "propfull" and <kbd>tab</kbd> twice. This will generate private and public field and property as following

```
    private int myVar;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }
```